# How to get character wise confidence in tesseract using command line?

Tags: tesseract, python-tesseract

I am able to get word level confidence score using tesseract 4.0 through the command line. Interested to know if there is a way to get the character confidence too.

For word level confidence used the below command:

```
tesseract [Image name] outputbase --oem 1 -l eng --psm 8 tsv
```

Comment: ,I also have same question like above ,if you found answer .please share to me....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Tesseract's hOCR output really contain bounding boxes and confidence levels for each character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15829148/does-tesseracts-hocr-output-really-contain-bounding-boxes-and-confidence-levels)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `hocr_char_boxes to 1` in your config file. Or, at the command line, your updated command would be:

```
tesseract [Image name] outputbase --oem 1 -l eng --psm 8 -c hocr_char_boxes=1 hocr
```

Note the hocr output option and look in that file for ...`_wconf`, e.g.

```
 <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_1_1' title='bbox 127 344 4618 6915; x_wconf 1'>
```

Let me know if this works for you, otherwise I'll just delete the answer.

Source: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/1465#issuecomment-513139976